# Phonegap Push Notifications for Phonegap IOS - Recommended solution

Tags: jquery, ios, html, cordova, push-notification

Can anybody recommend the best/cheapest route for implementing push notifications in a HTML5 Phonegap app?  I really have no idea where to begin.

I understand its pretty tricky to setup the system myself as I'm a front-end developer with minimal xcode dev experience - so I guess I'll need to implement an existing service such as Urban Airship?

I wondered if anyone had experience of Phonegap/IOS Push Notifications and could recommend a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this very good & very detailed article that walks you through the entire process of push notifications in PhoneGap for iOS devices:   http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/